# Can new users edit their migrated questions?

Tags: discussion, migration, comments

[This recent question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/165782/49251) was migrated here (correctly) from the CS Stack Exchange. The author of the question posted this answer (because they cannot comment):

> Whoever moved this question also disabled my ability to make changes, or comment.
>
> So I apologize for the confusion. I am obviously a beginner, this is all new to me.
>
> I really appreciate some of the kind thorough answers, and would love to clarify more things in the OP down the road.

The first part of this made me think. **If a user has enough rep to comment & edit on the original site, can/should they be able to comment & edit once the question is migrated?** Are the commenting and editing privileges lost because the question is migrated?

(In this case, OP doesn't have enough rep to comment in CS:SE, so it doesn't really matter... but my question stands.)

**update:** Question in question deleted per O.P.'s request.

Comment: I thought you can always edit your own posts, even with a rep of 1.  You can't comment until you get more rep, but then again new information about a question should go into the question anyway, not be hidden in a string of comments.

Comment: That's what I thought - is there any reason why OP wouldn't be able to edit their own post here? Is the migrated post owned by Community or something silly?

Comment: Incopentence is the first reason that pops to mind.

Answer (score 3):

The new user becomes an owner of his migrated question.  He should be able to comment and edit.

There may be a delay caused by caching.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, new users can edit their migrated questions. They first need to create an account on this site, using the same credentials that they used on the original site. Their account on this site will then be associated with the account on the original site. After the account is created, the new account will become the owner of any migrated post, but not necessarily of migrated comments.

There is a small delay during which some databases is out-of-date, so if the original poster creates an account, they will initially not have ownership of their migrated question. Waiting for a few minutes should do it.

Once the original poster gains ownership of their question, they will be able to edit it and to post comments on it, regardless of reputation.

In this specific case, as I write, the [original poster](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/72749/elegant-scripting) of [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/165782/wheres-the-error-in-this-breadboard-diagram) has gained ownership of the question and can comment on it and edit it.